# Why are template (non-static) member variables not supported in C++?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++14

While static member variables can be templated in C++14 this wont work:

```
class SomeClass
{
  public:

  template<typename T>
  T var = {};
};

int main()
{
  SomeClass instance;
  instance.var<int> = 50;
  instance.var<double> = 0.1;
}
```

What are the reasons, that templates for variable members are not supported by the C++ standard since it should be possible in principle?

Comment: What would be the `sizeof(SomeClass)`?

Comment: @tkausl `sizeof(SomeClass)` = sum of the size of all instantiated template member variables and the non-template members

Comment: @DariusDuesentrieb: That would require every piece of code that needed to know `sizeof(SomeClass)` to also know every piece of code that uses `SomeClass` in any of its many configurations. This is intractible. I cannot conceive of a way to do that in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiate the class you don't know how much memory it will use. Does this class contain an int and a double? What if you write

```
instance.var<float> = 0.2; 
instance.var<long long> = 1;
```

later in your code

Answer (score 2):

This would make two objects of the same type `SomeClass` different, rendering the class concept as we understand it in c++ useless.

Also your code sample implies that `var` could change type during runtime, this can be done using std::variant or std::any.

Answer (score 2):

It *cannot* be possible in principle or in practice, as the other answers explain: `sizeof(SomeClass)` would be impossible to compute in general, and `SomeClass` would no longer have any predictable or sane identity, defeating the purpose of its existence.

If there are only a select few types you wish to choose from, and you wish to change the "selected" type at runtime, perhaps a *variant* is what you're looking for?

```
#include <variant>

class SomeClass
{
public:
   std::variant<int, double> var = {};
};

int main()
{
   SomeClass instance;
   instance.var = 50;
   instance.var = 0.1;
}
```

(This [requires C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), but a Boost equivalent has been available for many, many years.)

It works because `var` will be as big as it needs to to store *either* an `int` or a `double` (plus some housekeeping), and this size is fixed no matter which "mode" your variant is in at any given time.

If you want to accept *any* type, you could use [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), which is like a variant on drugs. The overhead is a little heavier, but if your requirements are *really* so relaxed then this can do the job.

But if you want multiple variables, have multiple variables.

Answer (score 1):

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) has value types with known sizes.  All complete types in C++ that you can create can have their sizes calculated by the compiler based only on information at or above the line of creation within that compilation unit.

In order to do what you want, either the size of instances of a class varies with every template variable ever used in any compilation unit, or the size of instances varies over time as new elements are added.

Now you can create new data based on type, but it won't be inside the class; instead, you add a map storing the data.

```
using upvoid=std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)()>;
template<class T>
static upvoid make(){
  return { new T, [](void*ptr){ delete static_cast<T*>(ptr); } };
}
std::map<std::type_index, upvoid> m_members;
template<class T>
T& get() {
  auto it = m_members.find(typeid(T));
  if (it == m_members.end()){
    auto r = m_members.insert( {typeid(T), make<T>()} );
    it=r.first;
  }
  return *it.second;
}
```

now `foo.get<int>()` allocates an `int` if it wasn't there, and if it was there gets it.  Extra work would have to be done if you want to be able to copy instances.

This kind of mess emulates what you want, but its abstraction leaks (you can tell itmisn't a member variable).  And it isn't really a template member variable, it just acts a bit like one.

Barring doing something like this, what you ask for is impossoble.  And doing this as part of the language would be, quite frankly, a bad idea.

Comment: @darius yes, typo.

Comment: I watched this talk by Herb Sutter where he talks about metaprogramming: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AfRAVcThyA&t=19m11s 
Could it be possible to create effectively template member variables with something like this?: https://pastebin.com/PEfFuZmZ

Comment: @DariusDuesentrieb I'm not sure how functional metaprogramming is.  Metaprogramming with side effects (where you can modify a type not returned) might be able to enumerate all `T`s used for a given type and add them as member variables "retroactively"; functional (pure) metaprogramming less so.  It is in too much flux for me to be able to be certain of anything.