# Having a template compile for only known execution path

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, templates

In the example below I am having a issue with getting it to compile even though I know the known execution path will be "safe". By "safe" I mean I know I will only use it in this manner. Is there an algorithm or a better way to structure a scenario where even though I know I will never have a "Type" of "float" passed with a "kind" value of 1?

The error in particular I get is that

```
error C2248: 'foo::foo' : cannot access private member declared in class 'foo'
```

Test case example

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class foo {
private:
    foo(float val) {
        val = 99.0f;
    }
public:
    foo(int val) {
        val = 2;
    }
};

template<typename Type>
struct bar {
public:
    vector<Type> array;

    void Add(Type value) {
        array.push_back(value);
    }
};

class bunny {
    bar<float> floats;
    bar<foo> foos;
public:
    template<typename Type>
    void Initialize(int kind, Type value) {
        if(kind == 0)
            floats.Add(value);
        else if(kind == 1)
            foos.Add(value);
    }
};

int main(void) {
    bunny first; first.Initialize(0, 1.0f);
    //bunny second; second.Initialize(1, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a keyword `friend` which may help you.

Comment: I asume you make the foo(float) constructor private on purpose to test that it is or not used by the compiler? Anyway, I think you can do what you want using specialization on the Initialize() method.

Comment: @JorgeGonzálezLorenzo I have never heard of something such as "specialization" for the Initialize() method. How would that be done?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `kind` parameter?  If it's just there to say what type of `value` you have, there are better ways (using the type system) of doing that.

Comment: In the code above I see no need for `kind` at all.  I could tell the compiler to deduce which branch from the type of value.  Are you ok with eliminating kind?  Or must I write code that does UB if you get it wrong for no reason?

Comment: @Yakk I would be ok with getting rid of kind but I do not see a way without out.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I use it to know what "bar" fill in. Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can have multiple functions that have the same name but differ in number or type of the arguments, so, for example, you can have two functions:

```
void foo(float a)
{
    std::cout << "Float!" << a << std::endl;
}
void foo(int a)
{
    std::cout << "Int!" << a << std::endl;
}
```

If you call one of these functions the compiler will deduce what function to call based on the argument you gave to the function.
That is called function overloading.

In your case you could probably rewrite your bunny class to something like this:

```
class bunny {
    bar<float> floats;
    bar<foo> foos;
public:
    void Initialize(foo value) {
        foos.Add(value);
    }
    void Initialize(float value) {
        floats.Add(value);
    }
};
```

If you call `first.Initialize(1.0f)` the compiler knows that he needs to call `void Initialize(float value)` because you passed a float to the function.

Comment: I would like to use a template as there may be many "bar" lists and other functionality besides "Initialize". I only show one function here as a smallest test case.

Comment: Since you have different names for each 'bar'  list you will need to write specific code for each of them. You could make the bars static templates (`template<typename T> static bar<T> barObject;`, this is called Variable template, works since C++14) and use this function: `template<typename T> void Initialize(T value){ bar<T>.Add(value); }`. However you wont be able to use template member (non-static) variables. You could try to simulate them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49397130/6860744 but that's probably not worth the effort.